# event.preventDefault not working in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, preventdefault

I've followed a tutorial & they used `event.preventDefault()` on the `Save` button & save a form into the state. I've not really written the `input` tags yet but so far I've added the Save button and it kinda like reloads the page which it shouldn't be doing.

Here is my page component:

```
class manageLocationPage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
        this.state = {

        };
        this.SaveLocation = this.SaveLocation.bind(this);
    }

    componentWillMount() {

    }

    componentDidMount() {

    }

    SaveLocation(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("Saved");
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <LocationForm listingData={this.props.listingData} onSave={this.SaveLocation}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

My `locationForm` component:

```
const LocationForm = ({listingData, onSave, loading, errors}) => {
    return (
        <form>
            <h1>Add / Edit Location</h1>
            <TextInput />

        {/*Here below is where we submit out input data*/}
            <input type="submit" disabled={loading} value={loading ? 'Saving...' : 'Save'} className="buttonSave" onClick={onSave}/>
        </form>
    );
};
```

Did I miss something?

Comment: What if you use `form`'s `onSubmit` instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of onClick it your input.submit, you should do

```
const LocationForm = ({listingData, onSave, loading, errors}) => {
    return (
        <form  onSubmit={onSave}>
            <h1>Add / Edit Location</h1>
            <TextInput />

        {/*Here below is where we submit out input data*/}
            <input type="submit" disabled={loading} value={loading ? 'Saving...' : 'Save'} className="buttonSave"/>
        </form>
    );
};
```

So the event is the form submission which is being prevented.

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html#submitting-the-form

Comment: Also, I didn't include the `loading` props thats why it was causing the page reload behaviour. I've fixed it & yeah this method works too.